# Создание тегов в android

Tags: android, xml

Может есть пример создания таких тегов или какие-либо идеи

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это же обычные `TextView`

Comment: Вас затрудняет установление фона со скруглёнными углами или распределение элементов разной ширины вот таким образом?

Comment: Готовых реализаций [более чем достаточно](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=tagview+android&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults), можете использовать готовое. можете на основе чужого кода сделать свое решение.

Comment: Затрудняет, то, как переносить теги на другую строку, когда первая уже заполнена