# Создание тегов в приложении для Android

Tags: android, xml

Создаю `textView` динамически в `LinearLayout`'е

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но возникает вопрос, как быть, если тегов становится слишком много и они не помещаются в одну строку.  Как реализовать перенос на следующую?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто-нибудь знает как решить данную проблему

Comment: А чем вас готовые решения [из этого комментария](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541190/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-android#comment685201_541190) к вашему прошлому аналогичному вопросу не устроили?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой [android-flowlayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) или [FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout)
Так же есть официальное гугловское решение [FlexboxLayot](https://m.habrahabr.ru/company/speakasap/blog/300908/) с аналогичной и даже намного большей функциональностью.

Comment: FlowLayout очень помогло. Спасибо огромное

Comment: Есть официальное гугловское решение [FlexboxLayot](https://m.habrahabr.ru/company/speakasap/blog/300908/) с аналогичной и даже намного большей функциональностью

Comment: @pavlofff, добавлю в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите пожалуйста в сторону TableLayout.
Grid разметку по моему наверное тут лучше всего использовать.